# Is it possible to join merge same databases columns in SSIS?

Tags: database, join, ssms, data-warehouse, sql-server-data-tools

I have one database called Customer, I have 3 tables who are important, those are: CustomerID, CustomerToBillID and CustomerName. 
lets say we have a data set:

```
CustomerID = 1 with, CustomerName = John 
CustomerID = 2 CustomerName = Bert  
And the CustomerToBillID = 2 on both (so Bert only pays)
```

Is there a way that I can have two CustomerName columns? for example I want to 
use CustomerID with CustomerName and CustomerToBillID with CustomerName.

I tried to use a data conversion for CustomerName to make CustomerNameOne and mergejoin after sorting on CustomerToBillID,but this won't do it because he will be confused about the two CustomerName from the same database and just pick one CustomerID or CustomerToBillID, I use SSIS in virtual studio 2017 SSDT.

I can provide more information if needed.

**EDIT:** i want to output the following:

[image: before] Before

[image: After]After. 
Red circle has the wrong data. It has the CustomID 454 and not 401
Customer has now CustomerName and Bill to customer has the column CustomerNameOne.

**EDIT 2:** [image: right now]
This is how it is at the moment, the red circle are the same databases/tables, so getting CustomerName column from the second one will make it confused I think?

**Edit 3:** [image: simple]

to make it somewhat simple I want to do this, but this does not work because when CustomerID = 1 hits CustomerToBill = 1 then he will take CustomerID = 129 and change 1 too id 129, example in the following data result image:
[image: result]

In the red line it should be (head Office) not (Mineral Hills)

**EDIT 4:** [image: ??]

as for the comments i did what you asked only the blue lines give me the good output but the red lines are not corresponding to the BillTOID it just says the name of the CustomerID.

Comment: Ricardo, could you please post expected final output. It is not clear what you are trying to ouput.

Comment: I placed a edit on my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this, start with two Merge Joins, one with CustomerID to CustomerName and the other join using CustomerBillToID and CustomerName.  After this, add a third Merge Join using whatever unique key identifies that row (customer, order, etc.) and then you can output the only the necessary columns, including each CustomerName, from the prior joins.  You'll probably also want to alias each CustomerName appropriately as well.

Comment: how do i do this in SSIS because if i need to make 2 merge joins then i need 4 times the same database to sort them and merge them. i think that would be a little bit extensive.

Comment: If you do the sorts in the database, either via clustered index or use ORDER BY, you can remove the sort transformations from your package.  To do this, you will need to set IsSort to true and SortKeyPosition to 1 (assuming you sort by ASC) on the sorted column.  These properties can be found on the Input and Output Properties page of the Advanced Editor, by right-clicking the OLE DB sources.  This sorting will propagate and any subsequent sorts can also be omitted from the Data Flow Task.

Comment: but i mean if i need to make 2 merge joints i need to have 4 times the same table(column) sort them all and combine 4 database tables just to have 2 merge joints, i wanted to ask if there are another possibility to do this?

Comment: You can modify you OLE DB sources to use a SQL Command instead of the full table and only select the columns you need from each.  For instance, on the second join only select CustomerBillToID, CustomerName, and whatever column you plan to use to join back, which will also allow you to remove CustomerBillToID from your other OLE DB source, essentially spiting the table between the OLE DB sources to avoid redundant columns.

Comment: the problem is i need to use CustomerName twice, once for the normal name (customerName) and once for (CustomerToBilliD) i need to spilt that one to make a new column like (CustomarNameOne) and merge that one with (CustomerToBillID) and that i don't know how to do

Comment: In your source SQL statement, just select the CustomerName column a second time and alias it- i.e. CustomerNameForBillTo.  Another option is adding a derived column and just copying CustomerName, but doing this in the initial SQL query will likely have less overhead.

Comment: In the mapping for the flat file destination, are the CustomerNameToBill and BillToCustomerID fields mapped to the wrong ones?

Comment: No the last one CustomerNameToBill should only show : tailspin toys (head office)

Comment: You'll still need to use a separate OLE DB source and Merge Join to bring in the CustomerNameToBill/BIllToCustomer ID, unless that's being done in the database now.

Comment: Yea everything is in the same table, i just added CustomerName as CustomerNameToBill as sql command

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182153/discussion-between-userfl89-and-ricardo-buijsman).